# How to use KX_CharacterWrapper.walkDirection

Tags: python, game-engine

I want to make a character, which would move, and I want to use character physics and python for easyer controll. I know you get the character wrapper with `wraper = bge.constraints.getCharacter(own)` Then I want to make it move, but I can't figure out how `walkDirection` works. I did it like so:

```
import bge

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner

wraper = bge.constraints.getCharacter(own)
direction = (0, 1, 0)
wraper.walkDirection(direction)
```

But whnever I press the key and run the code I get an error: `'Vector' object not callable`
I can't find any examples of how that's done on the intrnet, and I tryed changing the code many times.

Please, can someone tell me how it's done?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `wraper.walkDirection` is a property of type `Vector` and not a function so you should do an assignment :

```
wraper.walkDirection = direction
```

to move in the local space orientation multiply the direction vector by the orientation matrix of the object :

```
direction = own.orientation*Vector((0, 0.1, 0))
```

you should include the Vector type by adding this line :

```
from mathutils import Vector
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works now. But is it possible to make the character move according to local rotation of the object (just like with `applyMovement(x, y, z), Local`)

Comment: @RokiPodpecan Updated the answer to include this

Comment: @RokiPodpecan thanks , I have added that : )